# What is the correct CommonJS structure for a Titanium project?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, commonjs

I'm starting a new Titanium app and want to use best practices and avoid having memory leaks from the get go. I'm new to CommonJS as well as the Titanium platform in general.

Unfortunately it seems that all the sample applications for titanium surround on `Ti.include("/lib/module")` instead of the [newer recommended best practice](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/x/I4CeAQ) of `require("/lib/module")`.

What I am worried about is the memory consumption of using CommonJS could require. From the [CommonJS Modules in Titanium documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/x/IYCeAQ) it states that modules will be cached, wouldn't this mean that if I ever access a module that all those functions suddenly stay around in memory even if they go out of scope?

I've started a new app with the following structure

```
/ctrl           # Model/UI controllers
/lib            # libraries (common + 3rd party)
/ui             # UI forms
/model          # DAL objects for data store
```

From here my main app has a single dashboard style view which is loosely structured as follows:

```
(function() {
    var getMenuItem = require("/ui/main").getMenuItem;
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title:'Main',
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    });
    var nav = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
        window:win
    });
    var sect;
    var data = [];
    sect = Ti.UI.createTableViewSection();
    data.push(sect);
    sect.add(getMenuItem("Customers",
        require("/ctrl/account").createCustMainWindow));
    sect.add(getMenuItem("Schedules",
        require("/ctrl/schedule").createScheduleMainWindow));
    sect.add(getMenuItem("Settings"));
    var menu = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        style: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
        data:data
    });
    win.add(menu);
    menu.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        if (e.rowData.createWindow) {
            var win = e.rowData.createWindow(nav);
            nav.open(win);
        }
    });
    var navWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
    navWindow.add(nav);
    navWindow.open();
})();
```

Any guidance on a correct project structure is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/appcelerator-titans/App) is the community app under development that purely uses module pattern, also look through the developer blog to find Forging series which have samples developed mostly using module pattern

Comment: That's perfect, the project structure is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I use require() and I have a long start of require() at the beginning of the project - wich might be one of the biggest Titanium project.

And I can be confident in saying that there is no visible cost in putting tousands of lines of code in these require statements.
However, you must constently check that your code has [no memory leaks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115811/what-are-some-of-the-best-ways-to-optimize-a-titanium-app)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the memory used by CommonJS module is released whenever the window is properly closed. Unless you assign the module to a global object, in that case it wouldn't be a leak.

Personally, I create a reusable factory. Actually, it depends on how complex the app is, if it's just a couple windows within NavGroup, I just write it straight up.

And don't forget to profile your app with Xcode instruments to make sure your app isn't leaking and if it does, it'll help finding the leak. Watch this [video for demo](http://vimeo.com/29804284) (about 1/3 way in).

Comment: According to the docs all CommonJS modules are cached. I tested this theory by creating a state full module and referred to in one window, closed, disposed and opened again, the state was retained. This is also explained on the appcelerator commonJS page that modules are state full. https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium#CommonJSModulesinTitanium-Caching